# my demo app of android for google map not working due to google play services showing error

Tags: android, google-maps

Error shown on android emulator :

> "Google Play services ,which some of your application rely on,  is not
>   supported by your device. Please contact the manufacturer for
>   assistance"

I have generated the key required to add in manifest, installed google play services and added reference to my project. my AVD is `android 4.2.2(17)`
I have also installed google api for android 4.2.2(17)
but still it isn't working.

Comment: u have to add support to your emulator for running MAP ver 2 app.. Check this link http://saleh.dsb-h.com/android-running-google-maps-api-v2-sample-in-emulator/

Comment: check out this post about maps api v2 http://rachitmishra.com/2013/08/the-maps-v2-api/

Comment: @barlop yup! my blog once! lost it because i was hosting it free! i will write a new one, till then removing this link!

Comment: sometimes old links e.g. http://saleh.dsb-h.com/android-running-google-maps-api-v2-sample-in-emulator/     http://rachitmishra.com/2013/08/the-maps-v2-api/  can be on archive.org       The salah one is though not the rachit one https://web.archive.org/web/20130826010647/http://saleh.dsb-h.com/android-running-google-maps-api-v2-sample-in-emulator/

Answer (score -1):

Google play services are not installed in the emulators. You have to manually install the APKs for the required services you want to run on the emulator. 
and as an alternative you can use [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator, they are pretty fast and come with google play services.

Comment: not sure that genymotion does anymore or if it does it's not by default last time I checked.

Comment: GM does not come with play services